# Extract text from a cell without extracting punctuation in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-replace

In Column F, I have a list of states and their abbreviations.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l50Rx.png)

I want to use a regex function to extract the state and the state code so the output looks like the contents in Columns G and H.

How do I do this? Thanks!

When I type in:

=regexextract(F3,"(\w+)(\s\w+)?")

The function works for states with one word names like Alaska and Florida, but separates the contents of multi-word states into multiple columns. it also fails to capture all three words in "District of Columbia". I could fix it to capture 3 words, but it wouldn't resolve the fundamental problem of keeping the output in a single cell in a single column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvjln.png)

I am at a loss of how to extract the state code from the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture word characters optionally repeated by a space and again word characters in the first group, and capture all between the double quotes in the second group.

```
=regexextract(F2,"(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*),""([^""]*)""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, a simple `SPLIT` will do the job.

```
=SPLIT(A1,",""")
```

Or as an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A,""",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

To extract everything before the comma:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A29,"[^,]*")
```

To extract everything after the comma:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A29,".*,(.*)")
```

`Alaska, "AK"` will return `Alaska` and `"AK"`